# TikZ matrix angle brackets mis-interpreted

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm newbie to TikZ.  When I use `<` and `>` in `matrix`, they are interpreted to some other symbols.  The following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=pdf2svg,multi=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of nodes] {
    <hello> & world\\
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will produce PDF and SVG:

```
¡hello¿ world
```

`<hello>` was translated to `¡hello¿`.

Question

1. Why?
2. How do I input angle bracket in `matrix`

Comment: This is unconnected to tikz, try `\begin{document}  <hello>  world\end{document}`  You could add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` although less than and greater than signs do not really make good angle brackets, better to use `$\langle$`  and `$\rangle$` or `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True.  I was using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` all the time but never really knew its purpose.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ad. 1. `<` and `>` give inequality marks **only** in math mode. You can write, e.g.,  `$<$`hello`$>$`. You have also symbols to use directly in text mode, but their names are longer than 3 characters, hence my suggestion.

Comment: So if not in math mode, they are interpreted otherwise?  For what purpose?

Comment: @gongzhitaao In the times of origin of TeX fonts needed a huge amount of computer processor and memory, hence the original ones have only 128 characters (and math font 256 characters) and in place of ASCII `<` and `>` there are in most of text fonts Spanish reversed `!` and `?`.

Comment: This is only true in OT1 encoding if you use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` you will get the expected symbols.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Certainly. This is the case of reverse compatibility. However I hope that such a simplification is proper for a newbie. Edit: Sorry, newbie in TikZ, not TeX.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Thanks for your excellent explaination.  Never knew that reverse `!` and `?` reason.